# Is there a way to load Word2Vec embeddings to ChromaDB?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, word2vec, large-language-model, chromadb

I want to query for similar words using ChromaDB. For example, 'great' should return all the words that are similar to 'great', in most cases, it would be synonyms. For this, I would like to upload Word2Vec or Glove embeddings to ChromaDB and query.

Most of the examples demonstrate how one can build embeddings into ChromaDB while processing the documents. As I have very little document, I want to use embeddings provided by Word2Vec or GloVe.

Is it possible to load the Word2Vec/Glove embeddings directly into ChromaDB?